# Query with_deleted records using pg_search and associated_against

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg-search, acts-as-paranoid

In my project, I have a model called `Log` that tracks all activities performed on an `Item`. `Item` can be soft deleted (using `acts_as_paranoid` gem). I implemented full-text search using `pg_search` to be able to search for logs that is associated to an item with a given `title`

Current `log.rb`

```rb
class Log < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch::Model

  # associations
  belongs_to :item

  # scopes
  pg_search_scope :search_log, associated_against: { item: %i[title] }, using: { tsearch: { prefix: true } }
  scope :list_feed, lambda { |search_text = nil|
    logs = all
    logs = logs.search_log(search_text) if search_text.present?
    logs
  }
end
```

This works well for `Item` that is not soft deleted, but now I want `pg_search_scope` to also be able to included soft deleted `Item`.

How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the paranoia default scope on `Item`, use `unscoped` in your query.